# Should CSS-related questions which do not have JavaScript tagged be answered with JavaScript?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags

Last month I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525867/do-not-apply-css-style-to-child-elements/15526151#15526151) as "Other" with the reason: "JavaScript isn't tagged, this isn't a valid answer."

The question itself doesn't ask for a JavaScript (or jQuery) solution - neither are tagged, nor are either mentioned. The answer I flagged, however, basically says that JavaScript is *probably* the only solution ([which isn't the case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15526165/1317805)), and then gives a jQuery solution - further deviating from the question's requirements.

My flag was declined with the reason: "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer".

Where this answer may be a *correct* JavaScript solution, it isn't a solution the asker was looking for.

1. Does this make it okay to answer CSS questions with JavaScript if JavaScript isn't mentioned?
2. Should JavaScript (and/or jQuery) therefore be tagged in the question to aide future users looking for a JavaScript solution?

Comment: Flags need to be handled by moderators. Incorrect answers can be handled by the community by downvoting them and this saves moderator time. If you encounter such answers again in the future, you should downvote them and if you feel the need, leave a comment explaining your reasoning although this is not something you need to do.

Comment: `Does this make it okay to answer CSS questions with JavaScript if JavaScript isn't mentioned?` I'd say use right tool for the right job. If some way is simpler, or the way OP wants is overkill, then we can suggest the right way to do it. If you are unsatisfied with some point in the answer then downvote or comment (or both).

Comment: `Does this make it okay to answer CSS questions with JavaScript if JavaScript isn't mentioned?` > there is no absolute ruling as to whether this is okay or not, but it's not up to mods to decide over it. Let the votes decide. That said, it is always okay to suggest other technologies in a **comment**.

Answer (score 4):

The "not an answer" flags are supposed to be used when a post is *not* an answer.

Like:

- "I have this issue too"
- "I tried this, but it didn't work"
- "Can you post a log"

Answers that are wrong are still answers.  If it's wrong, just down-vote.  It doesn't need to be deleted.

Also, I think it's fine to post solutions/suggestions with other (related) technologies.  It can stay un-deleted in case it helps someone else, but the question should *not* be re-tagged, as tags are about the *question* not its *answers*.

Sometimes JavaScript is the right answer, sometimes CSS is.  Just up/down vote the answers you like or dislike, no need to flag.

Answer (score 1):

In general **yes**.  It is very okay and good to answer *related* questions that are likely to either be highly relevant to the OP or very helpful for future visitors.  I would expect such an answer to receive a few upvotes and only be accepted if it's demonstrated that there is not a pure-CSS solution.